# Where is a static local variable object of function defined?

Tags: c++, static

I know that static member variables have to be defined out of the class somewhere (not in a header - in a TU), but I'm wondering then why the following works

```
#include <iostream>

class Logger {
public:
  static const Logger& GetInstance() {
    static Logger logger; // ??
    return logger;
  }

  void hello() const {
      std::cout << "Hello";
  }

private:
  Logger() {

  }
};


const Logger& logger = Logger::GetInstance();

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

  logger.hello();

  return 0;
}
```

Where is the object associated with `logger` defined? And why doesn't a function static variable require a definition/instantiation point as for a static class member variable?

Comment: No you don't have to and you can't define it anywhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *do* define it: in the function `GetInstance()`.

It's just that luck is on your side: that function is only encountered in *exactly* one translation unit (you've put the class definition in a source file), so the linker is not going to moan.

It would have been a different matter if the code were in a header and included in more than one translation unit.

Comment: so the point where I define a new object is `const Logger& logger = Logger::GetInstance();` ?

Comment: Indeed, the object is created when Logger::GetInstance() is *first* called.